# insert a string in an Url

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, url

```
string id = oUser.id.ToString();
 Image1.ImageUrl="http://graph.facebook.com/893914824028397/picture?type=large&redirect=true&width=500&height=500";
```

I want to replace `893914824028397` by string id

Comment: so... I hate to say this, but... what have you tried? there are a myriad of ways to do this - concatenation, replace, string.format, C# string interpolation, etc

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and share your research. Searching the web for "C# replace variable in string" yields hundreds of thousands of results, there's absolutely no need to ask that question again. If you did find something but it didn't work, then [edit] your question to include that, and explain what it does or doesn't do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [String Interpolation feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interpolated-strings) from C#6, so your code will look like:

```
string id = oUser.id.ToString();
Image1.ImageUrl=$"http://graph.facebook.com/{id}/picture?type=large&redirect=true&width=500&height=500";
```